# Android: get in-apps list from Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I'm implementing in-app billing for my app.
I've downloaded the sample application provided by Google Code, I've adapted it for my app and it works perfectly.

Now, I want to retrieve from Android Market the list of the in-apps published for my app and list them in my activity.

I need this because I won't publish my in-apps all at a time, but I want to publish some of them now, some of them next month and so on. I would like to avoid publishing a new apk version on Google Market as the people who downloaded the first version won't find the new available in-apps if they don't update their app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The In-App manager in the developer console does have an export to csv, so it is possible, in theory, to progmatically download the list.  It would probably require you having to write to code to "log in" to the developer console, store the access token, and then download file. (I don't think it would be trivial)

Another approach might be to store the list on a common server that's easier to access.

In either case, you are left with having to find the optimal interval in which to check for updates to your products.  ie, do you make the user wait each time you start the app, or do you have a manual action in the app where the user can check for updates.

Personally, unless your products are changing really frequently, I'd stick with the static list in the apk file.  You are probably going to be pushing out bug fixes, so updating the product list in those times, wouldn't be an issue.  As for notifying the user, they will get notified via the update manager that a new version of your App exists.  If the release notes  are interesting enough, users will update.